# Xml Rpc Exception on response

Tags: java, apache, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I am making a Apache xml rpc client call to xml server (Client version - 3.1.2 & server at 3.1.4)

When client call happens,i am getting runtime error :

[ XML_RPC, CLIENT ] XmlRpcClient failed to execute a transaction, cause: ClassCastException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.XmlRpcResponseParser.addResult(XmlRpcResponseParser.java:60)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.RecursiveTypeParserImpl.endValueTag(RecursiveTypeParserImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.XmlRpcResponseParser.endElement(XmlRpcResponseParser.java:186)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:186)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:115)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)

On debbuging i found that the the result in the api is expecting Map but what is passed as object is List.But this does not narrow down the problem.
I am moved server also to 3.1.2,but the runtime error won't go.